# Android приложение Профиль Firebase

Tags: android

Привет, помогите решить проблему, есть приложение на Firebase, нужно при регистрации занести информацию в базу и чтобы она потом вывелась в профиле, опишите процесс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень широкий вопрос, ответ такой же широкий.

1. Указываете провайдеров,с помощью которых вы авторизуете пользователей. Например, авторизация по емайлу.
2. Создаете ветку с пользовательскими профайлами в Firebase. Например, users.
3. В процессе регистрации создаете профиль пользователя в этой ветке и заполняете теми данные, которые вам нужны от пользователя.
   Например, в ветке users создаете профиль пользователя по его UID.
4. Собственно загружаете в профиль данные из этой ветки.